Cryptic Clue Explanation: Tree that's sported to keep visitors out at university (3)
Clue:

Tree that's sported to keep visitors out at university (3).

Answer:

 OAK

 OAK +S(=s sported) is a racing fixture named after the famous Epsom Derby, The Oaks. I have been unable to relate university or Oxbridge jargon, such as gated or up, to the rest of the clue.

Why?

Where is this clue from? e.g. if from a newspaper, what is the name of the newspaper and what day/week/etc. edition? Are you sure it is a cryptic clue, not just a crossword clue?

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

For one, this clue has appeared in the Ashburton Guardian on 03-Dec-16 and 21-Sep-19 (they genuinely reused a whole crossword!) Since crosswords like this often get syndicated out across many publications, I imagine it will also have turned up in other places too (so this might not be where the OP found it) but it's at least confirmation that it's out there in the public domain.


 To "sport the oak" means (in Oxbridge, or at least Cambridge, slang) to close the outer door of one's lodgings so as to indicate that no one should come in. E.g., in Samuel Butler's The Way of All Flesh, chapter 70: "Then there came an awful moment for both of us. A knock, as of a visitor and not a postman, was heard at my door. 'Goodness gracious,' I exclaimed, 'why didn’t we sport the oak? Perhaps it is your father.…'"


So the clue is a Rot13(PELCGVP QRSVAVGVBA)?

@LeppyR64 Indeed, that's what it seems here

For further context, this is in an old-fashioned type of room that has two doors in the same doorway - an inner one (called "the door") that doesn't have a lock, and an outer one ("the oak") that does. I haven't seen anything similar outside Oxbridge colleges.

This is also referenced in Clive James' autobiography, where the meaning is explained: https://archive.clivejames.com/books/um3-1.htm

"Sporting your oak" is an Oxbridge term meaning to keep your outer door closed (thus signifying that you are not available for casual visits).
See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sport_one%27s_oak
The term was in use when I was a student (1990s) though largely only as a joke when trying to sound extremely posh!

This seems to be the same as the answer from 9 hours ago. Please do not duplicate answers unless you have something substantial to add.

This answer valuably adds the information that the term is still commonly known in Oxford and Cambridge, even if regarded as a bit old fashioned.  There's no need to bite the chap's head off when he's trying to be helpful.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!  Your answer nicely compliments msh210’s answer by providing a dictionary reference and some personal experience.

@MikeSpivey It is not commonly known in oxford (based on my sampling). I studied there in the late 90s and have a lot of friends who have studied there at various times in various colleges as well as friends who studied at cambridge. A straw poll of them revealed that none of them had heard it at oxford though some think that maybe they have read it in a book... Obviously this isn't to say that it isn't used but I'd certainly not say it was commonly known.

@Chris It is obvious that our social spheres have been widely different.

Could well be! This is why I wanted to make it clear that it was a poll of my friends and not a statistically significant survey! :)
